# Ecmascript 6 and angular,angular grid autocomplete onSelect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-grid

onselect function doesn't work.can't find why? anyone who can help me??

```
loadAutoAllocationGrid() {
        this.autoAllocationGrid = {
            gridTitle: 'Allocations',
            remoteEnable: false,
            showColumnFooter: false,
            data: this.baseAcc.allocations,
            enablePaginationControls: true,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    field: 'code',
                    enableEdit: false
                },
                {
                    field: 'account',
                    textField: 'name',

                    dataSource: (filter) => {
                        return BASE_ACCOUNT_SERVICE.get(this).getAccountsAll([
                            {field: 'name', value: filter, operator: 1}
                        ], ['id', 'name']).then((response) => {
                            return response;
                        });
                    },
                    onSelect: function(row, col, item) { // can't call to this function
                      console.log(8481);
                        //row.entity = item;
                    },
                    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{row.entity.name}}</div>',
                    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/cellEditor/autoComplete'
                },
                {field: 'accDescription'},
                {field: 'description'},
                {field: 'parentage'}
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: not sure that is help you, try add fat arrow onSelect: (row, col, item) => { 
                      console.log('call');
                    }

Comment: Please show us where you call it.